# Class of a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, class

I code the following piece of code:

```
Object value = ....;
System.out.println(value.getClass()); 
Object internalValue = ((Object[]) value)[0];
System.out.println(internalValue.getClass());
```

That returns

```
 class [Ljava/lang/Object;
 class [I
```

I do not understand why the first call to getClass() does not return

```
 class [[I
```

And would like to know what I need to do to make it indeed return the appropriate type (that is [[I).

Thanks.

Comment: how is `Object value = ....;` supposed to compile?

Comment: The value comes from a complicated piece of code. What matters here is that this is a value of class int[][], but the getClass() method is not able to see past the first arrays of arrays, and hence thinks it is of class Object[].

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code and it outputs "[[I":

```
Object value = new int[3][3];
System.out.println(value.getClass()); 
Object internalValue = ((Object[]) value)[0];
System.out.println(internalValue.getClass());
```

I am not sure what is your "complicated piece of code"? :)